# How Long Should Data Collection Sets run in Windows Server Performance Montioring

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, performance, performance-monitoring

I currently have an application server and a database server both running on Windows Server 2008 R2. I have been tasked with generating a weekly report on the utilization of CPU, Memory and Disk. I am planning on using the default Performance Monitoring Data Collection Set Template in Windows Performance Monitor and was wondering what are the best practices for scheduling the job to run? My preference would be for the data collection set to start at the beginning of each week and stop at the end. Would this be overkill? Also, would performance monitoring drag down system performance?

The use of our application will most likely be very irregular. A number of batch jobs run at night and users are likely to access the system when they arrive at work in the morning, so I am worried that a smaller sampling window would miss the true system utilization.

Also, I found some basic tutorials for setting up data collection, but had trouble finding more general info on best practices for weekly performance management using Windows Performance Monitoring. If anyone has a good source please share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where are you logging to? An SQL Database? CSV File?

If it's going to an SQL Database, I used to just create a single job and let it log all day long, forever. Then you query the SQL server to get the data for the range that you're after. You can do this in Excel, or whatever other report builder you have.

I say "used to" because a few years ago I did away with the de-centralised Performance Logging and installed a central [Zabbix](http://www.zabbix.com/) installation that keeps and tracks all this information forever, providing trends and granular reporting.

In terms of load, I never saw any noticable performance penalty by running the performance logging. Given the number of times each server gets polled by Zabbix each minute to collect all the datapoints, it's really a trivial operation.